# Unable to locate adb.exe, can't open adb too

Tags: react-native, android-studio, android-emulator, expo, adb

I made optimization of disk size (simply delete all trash) and when i try to use expo cli - i get typical issue : "Can't open emulator , make it manually from D:/AndroidSdk/..." . I try to resolve this problem with reset SDK Manager, but it doesn't help, so i launch emulator from Android Studio (before i do it from expo host ). And i get another error, that doesn't make my fix-way more clearly : "Unable to locate adb.exe" . After that i try to reassign some enviroment variables (Like Adb in PATH), that might not have correct way, well - it doesn't work too. So in this time i reset all Android Studio and related garbage (excluding enviroment variables) . So what i get in last attempt :

Expo :

[image]

Classical variable :

[image]

Path :

[image]

By the way try to run with expo client:install:android - no result (evidently);
And after this manipulation expo (above) doesn't recognize my real phone Imao - casual error "Check Metro logs"

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing a few  environment variables.

1. `ANDROID_AVD_HOME`

   - This should point to a folder named avd (e.g C:%USERNAME%.android\avd)
2. `JAVA_HOME`

   - While `JAVA_HOME` can point to any java run time environment, I found that having it point the one Android Studio provides to be a pain saver. I once ran into a problem where my builds were failing and I had no idea why. After a lot of sturggle, I found that the java I had independently installed somehow conflicted with what react native was trying to do. Using the java provided by Android Studio made this problem never occur again (e.g. `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre`)
3. `ANDROID_HOME` & `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`

   - For me `ANDROID_HOME` and `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` point to the same folder

In PATH you need the point to the platform-tools and tools of the sdk folder. For an example, if the Android sdk folder was stored at E:\Android\sdk you would add:

- E:\Android\sdk\tools
- E:\Android\sdk\platform-tools

Also keep in mind that Windows being Windows, uses '\' and not '/'. I'm not sure if they sanitize this in environment variables, but I try not to risk it

If this doesnt resolve your problems, try running `react-native doctor`, as this may print a more verbose reasons react-native is failing (I'm just comparing my environment variables to what you show in your question)